# MIPS Recursion function to reverse order of the linked list

Tags: recursion, linked-list, mips, reverse

I am trying to do recursion function to reverse a linkedlist in MIPS. The part createLinkedList does'nt belont to me. I am trying to add Display_Reverse_Order_Recursively function to this code. I don't understand how to pass the linked list address in $a0 and I can't use the Display_Reverse_Order_Recursively function properly. Plez help me

`````
# 
    li  $a0, 10     #create a linked list with 10 nodes
    jal createLinkedList
    
# Linked list is pointed by $v0
    move    $a0, $v0    # Pass the linked list address in $a0
    jal     printLinkedList
    
    move $a0 , $v0 
    jal Display_Reverse_Order_Recursively
# Stop. 
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall

createLinkedList:
# $a0: No. of nodes to be created ($a0 >= 1)
# $v0: returns list head
# Node 1 contains 4 in the data field, node i contains the value 4*i in the data field.
# By 4*i inserting a data value like this
# when we print linked list we can differentiate the node content from the node sequence no (1, 2, ...).
    addi    $sp, $sp, -24
    sw  $s0, 20($sp)
    sw  $s1, 16($sp)
    sw  $s2, 12($sp)
    sw  $s3, 8($sp)
    sw  $s4, 4($sp)
    sw  $ra, 0($sp)     # Save $ra just in case we may want to call a subprogram
    
    move    $s0, $a0    # $s0: no. of nodes to be created.
    li  $s1, 1      # $s1: Node counter
# Create the first node: header.
# Each node is 8 bytes: link field then data field.
    li  $a0, 8
    li  $v0, 9
    syscall
# OK now we have the list head. Save list head pointer 
    move    $s2, $v0    # $s2 points to the first and last node of the linked list.
    move    $s3, $v0    # $s3 now points to the list head.
    sll $s4, $s1, 2 
# sll: So that node 1 data value will be 4, node i data value will be 4*i
    sw  $s4, 4($s2) # Store the data value.
    
addNode:
# Are we done?
# No. of nodes created compared with the number of nodes to be created.
    beq $s1, $s0, allDone
    addi    $s1, $s1, 1 # Increment node counter.
    li  $a0, 8      # Remember: Node size is 8 bytes.
    li  $v0, 9
    syscall
# Connect the this node to the lst node pointed by $s2.
    sw  $v0, 0($s2)
# Now make $s2 pointing to the newly created node.
    move    $s2, $v0    # $s2 now points to the new node.
    sll $s4, $s1, 2 
# sll: So that node 1 data value will be 4, node i data value will be 4*i
    sw  $s4, 4($s2) # Store the data value.
    j   addNode
allDone:
# Make sure that the link field of the last node cotains 0.
# The last node is pointed by $s2.
    sw  $zero, 0($s2)
    move    $v0, $s3    # Now $v0 points to the list head ($s3).
    
# Restore the register values
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)
    lw  $s4, 4($sp)
    lw  $s3, 8($sp)
    lw  $s2, 12($sp)
    lw  $s1, 16($sp)
    lw  $s0, 20($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 24
    
    jr  $ra

        
    
    
#=========================================================
printLinkedList:
# Print linked list nodes in the following format
# --------------------------------------
# Node No: xxxx (dec)
# Address of Current Node: xxxx (hex)
# Address of Next Node: xxxx (hex)
# Data Value of Current Node: xxx (dec)
# --------------------------------------

# Save $s registers used
    addi    $sp, $sp, -20
    sw  $s0, 16($sp)
    sw  $s1, 12($sp)
    sw  $s2, 8($sp)
    sw  $s3, 4($sp)
    sw  $ra, 0($sp)     # Save $ra just in case we may want to call a subprogram

# $a0: points to the linked list.
# $s0: Address of current
# s1: Address of next
# $2: Data of current
# $s3: Node counter: 1, 2, ...
    move $s0, $a0   # $s0: points to the current node.
    li   $s3, 0
printNextNode:
    beq $s0, $zero, printedAll
                # $s0: Address of current node
    lw  $s1, 0($s0) # $s1: Address of  next node
    lw  $s2, 4($s0) # $s2: Data of current node
    addi    $s3, $s3, 1
# $s0: address of current node: print in hex.
# $s1: address of next node: print in hex.
# $s2: data field value of current node: print in decimal.
    la  $a0, line
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall     # Print line seperator
    
    la  $a0, nodeNumberLabel
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    
    move    $a0, $s3    # $s3: Node number (position) of current node
    li  $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    la  $a0, addressOfCurrentNodeLabel
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    
    move    $a0, $s0    # $s0: Address of current node
    li  $v0, 34
    syscall

    la  $a0, addressOfNextNodeLabel
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    move    $a0, $s1    # $s0: Address of next node
    li  $v0, 34
    syscall 
    
    la  $a0, dataValueOfCurrentNode
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
        
    move    $a0, $s2    # $s2: Data of current node
    li  $v0, 1      
    syscall 

# Now consider next node.
    move    $s0, $s1    # Consider next node.
    j   printNextNode
printedAll:
# Restore the register values
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)
    lw  $s3, 4($sp)
    lw  $s2, 8($sp)
    lw  $s1, 12($sp)
    lw  $s0, 16($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 20
    jr  $ra
Display_Reverse_Order_Recursively:
    subi $sp, $sp, 8 #push (save) the list pointer and return adress parameter to the stack
    sw $a0, 0($sp)
    sw $ra, 4($sp) 
    bne $a0, $zero, recursiveCase #if list pointer is not null: recurse
    #baseCase:
        addi $sp, $sp, 8 #do nothing in the base case, filled the stack
        jr $ra 
    recursiveCase:
        lw $a0, 0($a0) #update to the successor
        jal Display_Reverse_Order_Recursively #recurse
        lw $a0, 0($sp)
        lw $ra, 4($sp) 
        addi $sp, $sp, 8 #push (save) the list pointer and return adress parameter to the stack
        lw $a0, 4($a0) #print the item on the top of the stack
        li $v0, 1 
        syscall
        la $a0, seperator #print a space
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        lw $a0, 0($sp)
        jr $ra #return to the caller

    
    
    
#=========================================================      
    .data
line:   
    .asciiz "\n --------------------------------------"

nodeNumberLabel:
    .asciiz "\n Node No.: "
    
addressOfCurrentNodeLabel:
    .asciiz "\n Address of Current Node: "
    
addressOfNextNodeLabel:
    .asciiz "\n Address of Next Node: "
    
dataValueOfCurrentNode:
    .asciiz "\n Data Value of Current Node: "
seperator:  .asciiz     " " ````
`````

Answer (score 0):

`printLinkedList` is not a function, it does not return a value.

So, this code doesn't make sense:

```
jal     printLinkedList

move $a0 , $v0    # <<--- nothing interesting in $v0 here
jal Display_Reverse_Order_Recursively
```

---

This code sequence at the end of `Display_Reverse_Order_Recursively` fails to undo the stack frame that it created upon entry.

```
    lw $a0, 0($sp)
    jr $ra #return to the caller
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to retain the value stored in `$v0` before calling printLinkedList, since this is what holds the address of the linked list, which needs to be passed to the other function. By convention `$v0` is not assumed to have the same value after a function call, nor is `$a0`. And if you look through printLinkedListed you will see that a. neither register is stored on the stack but b. both registers' values change. So you cannot just move `$v0` to `$a0` again.

What you could do is `move $s0, $v0` before calling printLinkedList, and then `move $a0, $s0` afterwards, since `$s0` is a saved register. Or you could push `$v0` onto the stack before making that call, then pop it off afterword.